# Excel VBA CountIfs run-time error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to come up with the frequency of observations based on user-determined observations and bins and using the following code

```
Sub Button()

Set obs = Application.InputBox("Observations", Type:=8) 'select w/o label
Set bins = Application.InputBox("Bins", Type:=8) 'select w/o label

binsrow = bins.Rows.Count

For i = 1 To binsrow

    bins.Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 1) = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(obs, ">" & bins.Cells(i, 1), "<=" & bins.Cells(i + 1, 1))

Next i

End Sub
```

I get Run-Time Error '1004' when I run it as it is above. However, it does what the code tells exactly when I omit one of the conditions appearing in CountIfs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a second range argument for the second condition. Perhaps

```
WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(obs, ">" & bins.Cells(i, 1), obs, "<=" & bins.Cells(i + 1, 1))
```